# Forward HTTP access to another IP address in iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Hi I am using my local internet provider whenever I visit any page and when I look at a source code of the page there is a script injected into code
        http://10.80.196.101:8080/www/default/base.js'>

I have tried to access this IP but it is not working may be server down, so what I want to do is to forward this IP address to my local IP 127.0.0.1 or any other server where I will open 8080 port and will return 404 page whenever my browser call this script "http://10.80.196.101:8080/www/default/base.js" 
I am using Ubuntu and I also have OSX. any suggestion will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you using Zong 4G? I am facing same problem but just on Zong 4G not other ISPs

Answer (score 1):

So you visit any page - like this one - and it tries to load that script? That might be a trojan on your machine, or your provider trying to insert that script into all pages you visit. As you experience this on different machines, and different OSes, it seems to be your provider, or maybe your router.

To [block one IP address](http://www.codero.com/knowledge-base/questions/322/How+to+block+IP+address+in+Linux+via+ssh%3A):

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

If you're on [Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-block-an-ip-address-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-linux-server/) or Debian, you probably use `ufw` instead of iptables. Then use that to block the script.

```
sudo ufw deny from 192.168.1.5 to any
```

Comment: First of all it should be "iptables -I OUTPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP" no INPUT, also your second suggestion ufw doesnt work at all I don't want to block that IP i want to forward all the traffic to another IP address. for example we add entries to host file and map domain to another IP address I want same thing but IP to IP

Comment: Any Idea where do I run this command on windows? I tried command prompt, but it said 'iptables' is not recognized.

Comment: Actually these commands are for linux.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command in your case:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.80.196.101 -j REJECT
```